# Expo Branch: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNBranch.STANDARD EVENT ADD_TO_CART')

Tags: react-native, expo, branch.io

I am using expo for my react native application.

Steps:
 - run `expo start`

Hit the error below on android studio emulator.

Working fine on real android device and IOS simulator.

UPDATE:

**I have solved the issue. The issue was with my android studio. I open the app using the genymotion emulator and it was working**

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Branch does not officially have a wrapper SDK for Expo and the link you referenced is built by a third-party which we cannot help troubleshoot. 
Can you try ejecting your build from Expo and use native packages and linking in React Native, by following this: https://docs.branch.io/apps/react-native/#integrate-branch

Comment: Sorry I might not be clear when explaining. I have solved the issue. The issue was with my android studio. I open the app using the genymotion emulator and it was working. Thanks.